# SPARQL query doesnt work on another dbpedia resource

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

So when I [run this SPARQL query on the DBpedia SNORQL interface](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select%20*%20%7B%20%3Fs%20rdf%3Atype%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FCompany108058098%3E%20%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010) it works --

```
select *
  { ?s rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098> }
limit 10
```

But a [similar query doesn't work](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select%20*%20%7B%3Fs%20dct%3Asubject%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage%2FNEC%3E%20%7D%0D%0Alimit%205) --

```
select * 
  { ?s dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/page/NEC> }
limit 5
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Well, what is the goal of the second query? And why `http://dbpedia.org/page/` as namespace? Mostly, the resources in DBpedia use `http://dbpedia.org/resource/` as namespace. Moreover, I don't think the resource should be in object position given that the property is `dct:subject` which is supposed to map to categories. To be honest, I don't think you understood RDF or SPARQL, and you should do some more research in that direction. Just using an randomly generated query will most likely fail...

Comment: The working query is probably `select * {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/NEC> dct:subject  ?o }
limit 5` - note, it's just a guess as you didn't mention the purpose ...

Comment: @AKSW I was testing the second query based on the fact that first one worked. So I was testing a similar query on different company.

Comment: @AKSW also can u tell me why you used ?o and not ?s as in my first query. Secondly you used ?o in last ?

Comment: @AKSW thanks but your query isnt working for this organization http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=select+*+%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fpage%2FTata_Group%3E+dbo%3AparentCompany+%3Fo%7D%0D%0Alimit+5

Comment: I used `?o` because it's just why I'm used to when asking for the object of an triple. You know, RDF triple = `(s p o)` - an fact, you could also use any other var name, it doesn't matter. `?o` makes much more clear that it's the object. You could also use speaking names like `?category` or whatever.

Comment: Well, it's not working because you didn't read my comment carefully...`http://dbpedia.org/page/` is just used in a web browser to represent the HTML view of the RDF resource. Please read about Linked Data in that case. It has to be `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Tata_Group>`

Comment: And your first query worked, but is totally different compared to your second query. You should also first understand what the difference is between both. The meaning of `rdf:type`, please read about it.